# Using pushViewController is very slow on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to move from one `UIViewController` to another using `-pushViewController:animated` using the below snipped :

```
 SomeController *tabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mycus"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
```

Moving from one `UIViewController` (which has no `UIViews` or images) has a 3 second delay before moving. What is causing this issue and how would I solve it?

Comment: Why don't you use segue ?

Comment: Are you on a background thread / queue when you make this call?

Comment: @rckoenes So in his code what's that mean if it's not storyboard... ? [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mycus"]; ???

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot Your are totally correct, ignore my comment :(

Comment: All, I've used this above snippet in button action. did this wrong representation of push viewcontroller? Also Do I need to push the viewcontroller within the prepareForSegue method?

Comment: Cleaned up grammar and code formatting

Comment: Cleaned up grammar and code formatting. Added objective-c tag

Comment: in the end what was the problem. I have the same

Answer (score 0):

For storyboard, click on the segue you have created, give it an identifier like "someSegue".

Next you will want to trigger the prepareForSegue delegate in your viewcontroller doing the following...

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SomeSegue" sender:nil];
```

..Then you will want to include the delegate method in your view controller and do any preparing you might want before the next view controller is initialised.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

SomeController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

// Here you will want to do your prep e.g. pass iVars etc from one controller to the other.

}
```

Comment: I've tried the above. all code works fine when the destination view controller having less UIView and UIImages. but I've the destination viewcontroller contain large no of uiviews. In this case only it get delay in moving. Please advise on this. Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is the amount of UIViews zapping up memory, there might be another way around your problem if you post your code and perhaps a picture of your storyboard.

Comment: I couldn't share storyboard details right now. But I can give the details about my destination controller - Which contains three tabs, each tab will have no of UIView which has designed in the storyboard and constraints made correspondingly. could you now suggest how to resolve this cases?

Comment: It sounds like you are initialising all your views in ViewDidLoad when the second view controller is presented, even though they aren't yet visible, it's impossible to advise on a memory issue without any code. The best thing you can do is go to 'Product' -> 'Profile'  once the profiler has loaded click on Time Profiler Template, then press record. From there you can find which processes are the most demanding.